# Create DropDownList with OptGroup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I'm attempting to create a drop down list from one table in my database grouped by names from a different table in the same database.

What I have is a table that holds a bunch of units. These units belong to parent units. The tables are joined on the parent units id. So for the Units table, there's a property Parent, data type int. The ParentUnit table has an Id data type int, and a Name.

What I want to do is create a drop down list with all the Units group together by the Parent's Name. Unfortunately, this needs to happen inside the Controller and **NOT** the Model.

The other peace is, the drop down list is part of a workorder request form. So in the Workorder Controller, I need to create a SelectList with the optionGroup of Name of the Parent Unit.

How do I go about doing this?

This is what I'm thinking:

```
ViewBag.UnitId = new SelectList(db.Units.ToList(), "Id", "Name", ParentUnit.Name);
```

but I don't know how to implement it since I'm new to MVC.

When I tried `ViewBag.UnitId = new SelectList(db.Units.ToList(), "Id", "Name", "Parents", 1);`, the IDs of the Parents showed up in the optGroup, I'm guessing because the Id of the ParentUnit is stored in the Units table. How can I get the Name of the Parent to show up?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, First, it's better to change your model,
So you can have both tables (models) in one model with self-relation, for example, your model can be:

```
public class Model_Name
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public int ParentId { get; set; }
public Model_Name model_name { get; set; }
public ICollection<Model_Name> Model_Names{ get; set; }
}
```

---

And then implement your view model layer (DTO) as below;

```
public class View_Model_Name
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Title {get;set;}
public int ParentId {get;set;}
public int ParentTitle {get;set;}

}
```

---

Then for the implementation option group, you need to get a Dictionary of data, same as below:

```
public Dictionary<long,List<View_Model_Name>> GetGroupAndChilds()
        {
            var result = _yourcontext.Model_Name
                .Select(x => new View_Model_Name
                {
                    ID = x.ID,
                    Title = x.Title,
                    ParentId = x.ParentId,
                    ParentTitle=x.Model_Names.Title,
                }).AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.ParentId).ToList();

            return result.ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.ToList());
        }
```

---

Now you have a list of your data and you can use it in the presentation layer (Razor Page) as below:

```
public List<SelectListItem> showlist = new List<SelectListItem>();
public List<SelectListItem> GetList()
        {
            var allList= GetGroupAndChilds();
            foreach (var (key, value) in allList)
            {

                var parentTitle = GetDetails(key).Title; //you can write a function to get title from Id
                var group = new SelectListGroup() { Name = parentTitle };
                foreach (var per in value)
                {
                    var item = new SelectListItem(per.Title, per.ID.ToString())
                    {
                        Group = group
                    };
                    showlist.Add(item);
                }

            }
```

---

And finally, add the below tag to your cshtml (view) page;

```
<select asp-for="Your_Page_Model.YourItem" asp-items="Model.showlist"></select>
```

Finish